# how to remove id after extension in paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

how do remove id after ? in paperclip, I need only file_name.extension, when I copy image link I am getting:

```
/images/company_informations/s200/logo.jpg?1313497842
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `:use_timestamp => false` to the attachment resource configuration, as in

`has_attached_file :attachment,
      :use_timestamp => false,...`